# How to get Subdivision Surface Modifier to high levels without Blender crashing?

Tags: subdivision-surface, displacement, 3d-printing

Recently gotten into 3D printing and I've been getting models from games that have no official figure merchandise so I can make them a reality.

The problem is that, as is with most games, a lot of detail is faked using normal maps. So I decided to make those details part of the actually models using the displacement modifier. But the displacement modifier requires subdivision to make the displacement look good.

My PC has 12GB of VRAM and using 6 levels of subdivision takes up about 8.6GB. The displacement looks pretty decent at this level, but I believe it can look better at 7, 8 or even 10 levels. Most of the time when I try to go to 7 or above, blender crashes or completely destroys the mesh into black lines. I'm hoping that there is someway I can get higher levels without Blender crashing.

If anyone knows how to fix this or a better way of converting normal map detail into actual mesh geometry I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Just to be sure..  the level of subdiv you're asking for does not exceed the resolution of your printer?

Comment: Have you tried subdividing in small steps - like Subdivision at level 4 - apply modifier and then subdivision gradually to at level 3 o4  - apply modifier? This will give you a total of 8 subdivisions without change of quality. Is your mesh all quads or all triangles. Subdivision modifier performs poorly on high density triangular meshes.

Comment: Get a computer with more RAM